# How to pass functions as arguments inside modules?

Tags: erlang

The question I am trying to solve is

```
Write a split(L) which returns {Even, Odd}.
```

The available code I have looks like

```
-export([even/1, odd/1, filter/2, split_using_filter/1]).

even(Integer) -> Integer rem 2 =:= 0.
odd(Integer) -> not even(Integer).

filter(F, L) -> [T || T <- L, F(T) =:= true].

split_using_filter(L) -> Even = filter(fun(X) -> X band 1 == 0 end, L),
  Odd = filter(fun(X) -> X band 1 == 1 end, L),
  {Even, Odd}.
```

What I am doing now is passing

```
fun(X) -> X band 1 == 0 end
```

as `even` function and similarily for `odd`

**Question**
Is there a way to pass `even(Integer)` function as argument to `filter`? rather than re-writing the logic?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your code here:

```
split_using_filter(L) -> Even = filter(fun(X) -> X band 1 == 0 end, L),
  Odd = filter(fun(X) -> X band 1 == 1 end, L),
  {Even, Odd}.
```

did you mean you want to do it following???

```
split_using_filter(L) -> 
  Even = filter(fun even/1, L),
  Odd = filter(fun odd/1, L),
  {Even, Odd}.
```

Comment: Yes, exactly, I was not sure how to pass `even(X)` as argument. Is it recommended/good practice to pass it like `fun even/1`?

Comment: Alternative style is, if the function is small, write lambda like your example is not bad. BTW, for beautiful look, write like @BlackManba 's answer, but I don't think that answer code would compile, it should write variables `Even` and `Odd` binding `fun` in function body.

Answer (score 1):

```
Even = fun(X) -> X rem 2 =:= 0 end.
Odd  = fun(X) -> X rem 2 /= 0  end.
filter(F, L) -> [T || T <- L, F(T) =:= true].
split_using_filter(L) -> 
    {filter(Even, L), filter(Odd, L)}.
```

You can read this http://learnyousomeerlang.com/higher-order-functions

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide some explanation for why it does so.